# MyBatis Generator single resultMap

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

Im using MyBatis Generator to generate JavaBean and Mapper.xml.

But the Mapper.xml is different as I expected .

Mapper.xml contain two resultMap, `BaseResultMap` and `ResultMapWithBLOBs`.

I only want one resultMap contain all column.

Comment: Are you sure that ResultMapWithBLOBs isn't extending the BaseResultMap?

Comment: ResultMapWithBLOBs does extending BaseResultMap. But I just want a single resultMap that contains all columns, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Tough to know how you have your mybatis generator configuration set up, but the way to do this is through configuring the context's Model Type.

MBG provides an enum called [ModelType](https://github.com/mybatis/generator/blob/master/core/mybatis-generator-core/src/main/java/org/mybatis/generator/config/ModelType.java) which allows you to control how the Java Model classes (your beans) are generated.  You want to use `ModelType.FLAT` in your context configuration to avoid any extra bean classes being created.

Answer (score 0):

One option to avoid the creation of "WithBlobs" subclasses is to specify `<columnOverride/>` to use non-Blob jdbc types in your generator config for the Blob columns.

So, in the example of a `TEXT` column named "bar" in your table, you can specify `VARCHAR` instead:

```
    <table tableName='foo' domainObjectName='Foo'>
        <property name='useActualColumnNames' value='true' />
        <columnOverride column="bar" property="bar" jdbcType="VARCHAR" /> 
    </table>
```